# External ID Concept?

Tags: java, hibernate

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;

    private String externalID; //<--- why we need this?

}
```

Someone has suggested me to include an external Id field in a class something like that? Any suggestions why that could be?

Comment: What is externalId suppose to represent? What is the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, what exactly meant by `externalID` here, since the case of usage is not clear.
But, I assume a couple of cases:

### 1. External service

External id may be used to map your entity with some id of another resource from different services. Something, that identifies this entity in another system.

**For example**: in `externalID` may be stored person twitter id or bank account id.

### 2. Security-wise

`externalID` is used to protect (encapsulate) internal `id` been visible outside, which may cause some security vulnerabilities.

**For example**: 
In your case, internal `id` is Integer with `GenerationType.AUTO`, that means, all entities will have an incremental id: 1, 2, 3, ... 
Knowing that someone may analyze your API calls and easily iterate through all your accounts via API, e.g: `GET api/person/{id}`.

Usually, a different type of IDs is used to solve this problem, like UUID, e.g.: `8b9af550-a4c7-4181-b6ba-1a1899109783`. Which can be used as `externalID` in your case.
So, I assume this is the reason to add additional `externalID` to your entity.

**Note**: if your Database supports the usage of UUID (or store it as String), you can simply replace your internal id type with `UUID` and get rid of `externalID` here.

Comment: Thanks a lot ish !!  if it is for security purposes, how it will help enhancing the security exactly? if I am not wrong you mean to say let say when we create a new person we won't take id input from the personDTO (of course) and will we have to assign a id to him, so we would be assigning external id to him? is that what you mean?

Comment: In case of security: if id with type Integer will be externally visible, then it will be clear what IDs your account if the database has. So, lets, my user has id -> `32`, and somehow I have broken your security and call some APIs. From this point, its clear to me how to get data for other accounts, since my id is `32` and I will try to use this broken API with id `33` or `72` and will see what data I will get. But in the case of UUID, I can't guess id of other accounts in your system.'

Comment: In other case: yes, your example with `personDTO` is correct. Ideally, all ids should be created internally on the server.

Comment: Oh yeah, I got it !! Just one more think, since we are speaking of security. During CRUD operation what should I return ? lets say we create a person using person dao what should be the return type of create operation?

Comment: I mean, we cant return the whole object as that would include the id.

Comment: yes, you are right, we can't return the whole object. So, you can create some PersonDto, will be the same but without `int id` filed, and use it for all your CRUD operations with external id.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of same, Thanks a lot to clear all my doubts, your awesome bro !!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that externalID represents the Primary Key of another table that person is relative to. String is quite arbitrary though, you would generally use an Integer, Long, or UUID to represent a primary key. Might need more context in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose behind an external ID is to link your entity with another representation of it from a system that is **decoupled** from yours.

For example, if you want the store the Facebook ID for SSO reasons, you would do it through a field that could be called `externalId`, or something like that. Another example might be that you imported some accounts from another database, and you want to store the Primary Key from the source entity that has been imported.

Otherwise, if that field does not represent anything in your business logic, get rid of it.